# Get content between matching template tags

Tags: php, templates

How can I get the contents from `{@if condtwo}` to the matching `{!if}`?

```
{@if condtwo}
    {@if condone}
        show this if condone is true
    {!if}
other contents
{!if} <- matching {!if}
```

I tried using `preg_match_all`. Here's my regular expression:

```
/([\s]*?{@IF(.*?)}[\s]*?)(.+?)([\s]*?{!$IF}[\s]*?)/si
```

The problem is that it only gets all the contents from `{@if condtwo}` to the next `{!if}`:

```
{@if condtwo}
    {@if condone}
        this is a table
    {!if}
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse those using regular expressions. Although PHP supports recursive matching (at least, I think it does) - you really shouldn't do it. It's messy.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know I said not to use regular expressions, but... I lied. This will do it, and it's probably the best way to do it, too.

```
/{@if(.+?)}(((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*){!if}/si
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://ideone.com/DYtyz) You might also want to take a look at [the documentation for recursive regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

Comment: ok so you mean I can use it now? I was about to redo my codes all over again

Comment: @kapitanluffy: Yes, you can use it now :) It actually wasn't as messy as I thought originally. Sorry.

Comment: do you mind to explain me how it works? i understand most of it but not the ?R and the ?>[ parts

Comment: @kapitanluffy: `?>` is a once-only subpattern that's only used for efficiency; the regular expression will work without it, but you should keep it in. The `?R` means "match the entire regular expression again" - it's what enables recursion. You can check the documentation I linked to for a little more thorough explanation.